# Как отключить автозамещение импортов в одну строку с ".*" в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Есть импорт нескольких элементов с одного kotlin-класса. При импорте третьего элемента они все сливаются в один импорт

`"import class.*"`

Как отключить данную функцию и оставить изначальное кол-во строк импорта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это все настраивается в **Preferences**.
Открываете через меню (на Маке: **Android Studio** -> **Preferences**).
Там находите **Editor** -> **Code Style** -> **Kotlin**, закладка **Imports**.

В выпадающем меню **Scheme** выбираете что меняете -- настройки открытого проекта или IDE по умолчанию.

В самих настройках думаю нет проблем разобраться.